# The delete keyword is not working even though when I build the code it say there are not errors

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>

class Cd {
private:
    const char* performers;
    const char* label;
    int selections;
    double playtime;
public:
    Cd(){
        int eight = 8;
        performers = new char[eight];
        label = new char[eight];
        label = "Unknown";
        performers = "Unknown";
        selections = 0;
        playtime = 0.0;
    }
    Cd(const char* performers, const char* label, int selections, double playtime) {
        this->performers = new char[strlen(performers)+1];
        this->performers = performers;
        this->label = new char[strlen(label) + 1];
        this->label = label;
        this->selections = selections;
        this->playtime = playtime;

    }
    void setLabel(const char* label) {
        this->label = label;

    }
    void setPerformers(const char* performers) {
        this->performers = performers;

    }
    void setSelections(int selections) {
        this->selections = selections;

    }
    void setPlaytime(double playtime) {
        this->playtime = playtime;

    }
    const char* getLabel() {
        return label;
    }
    const char* getPerformers() {
        return performers;
    }
    int getSelections() {
        return selections;
    }
    double getPlaytime() {
        return playtime;
    }
   

    virtual void Report() {
        std::cout << "Performers: " << performers<<std::endl
         <<"Label: " <<label<< std::endl
        <<"Number of selections: " << selections << std::endl
        <<"Play time: " << playtime << std::endl;

    }

    ~Cd() {
        delete[] performers;
        delete[] label;

    }
};

class Classic : public Cd {
private:
    const char* primaryWork;
public:
    Classic() {
        primaryWork = new char[8];
        primaryWork = "Unknown";
    
    }

    Classic(const char* primaryWork, const char* performers, const char* label, int selections, double playtime) {
        this->primaryWork = new char[strlen(primaryWork) + 1];
        this->primaryWork = primaryWork;
        setLabel(label);
        setPerformers(performers);
        setSelections(selections);
        setPlaytime(playtime);
    }
    virtual void Report() {
        std::cout << "Primary work: " << primaryWork << std::endl<< 
            "Performers: " << getPerformers() << std::endl <<
            "Label: " <<getLabel()  << std::endl<<
            "Number of selections: " << getSelections() << std::endl
            << "Play time: " << getPlaytime() << std::endl;
    
    }
    ~Classic() {
        delete[] primaryWork;

    };

};
int main()
{
        Cd c1("Beatles", "Capitol", 14, 35.5);

        Classic c2 = Classic("Piano Sonata in B flat, Fantasia in C", "Alfred Brendel", "Philips" , 2, 57.17); 

        Cd* parent = &c1;
            std::cout << "\nUsing object directly:\n";
        std::cout << "***************************" << std::endl;

        c1.Report();
        c2.Report();
 
        std::cout << "\nUsing type cd * pointer to objects:\n";
        std::cout << "***************************" << std::endl;

        // Call Report() using Cd type pointer created above 
        parent->Report();
        Classic* classic = &c2;
        classic->Report();

        // Call Report() using Cd type pointer containing Classic object address 

        return 0;
    
}
```

I don't understand what is wrong with the `delete` keyword. My code is supposed to delete the memory allocation for the array at the end to save memory, but it is not working. The `delete_scalar` file pops up and the code does not finish executing. The rest of the code is working fine. The big problem is when I build the code the compiler tells me that there are no errors found.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three overload copy constructor and assignment operator properly.

Comment: Using `new`, assigning the result to a `const char *`, then immediately setting that `const char *` to a literal string does not really do what you think it does, that's the problem. Your C++ textbook should have examples of doing that: using new to allocate a buffer of characters then populating it. Is that how your C++ textbook's example does this?

Comment: Off-Topic:  If you use a different naming scheme between members and parameters, you won't need to use the `this->` syntax.

Comment: `primaryWork = new char[8]; primaryWork = "Unknown";` allocates some memory and then leaks it by assigning the pointer to a string literal which cannot be deleted since it was not allocated with `new`. Use `strcpy` to copy the string into the allocated memory if that is your intent. Consider using `std::string` instead of manual dynamic allocation.

Comment: Prefer to use `std::string` and you can eliminate a lot of dynamic memory issues.

Comment: Well, you can fail a written test if you write nonsense, even if your grammar is impeccable...

Comment: The fact you mention Alfred Brendel motivates me to answer this - my very accomplished violinist wife has worked with him, along with his boy Adrian. Upvoting for that!

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: Exactly! I still use `m_` for class members and `s_` for statics. Indeed syntax highlighters somewhat reduce the need for that, but alas *vi* doesn't support them and occasionally one has to resort to using *vi* as your editor.

Answer (score 1):

Write

```
std::string performers;
```

instead of

```
const char* performers;
```

and so on for the other string-like members. Then you can drop the `new[]` and `delete[]` entirely. The bug you have is a reassignment of the pointer to some read-only `const char[]` type `"Unknown"` which compiles due to the rules of *pointer decay*.

Using bare pointers for class members also means you need to write constructors, a destructor, and an assignment operator correctly. If you use `std::string` then you can rely on the compiler-generated ones.